# How do i configure the right click menu in the 'project explorer' view?

Tags: eclipse

I installed a fresh eclipse and i have a problem : when i right click somewhere in the project explorer view, the menu is missing some links and some that i dont' want to see are there.

How can i modify that ?

Bonus question : i can't rename files, folders, classes, nothing. The 'rename' link in the toolbar (it doesn't appear in the right click menu !) is disabled.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I can only answer your bonus question. Rename in Eclipse is only available in Navigator view. But you can use Refactor->Rename in other views as well. The bahavior is slighly different from normal Rename but most of the time, it is what you wanted.

Comment: at work, i use the same version of eclipse, and i can rename files in my project explorer view

http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/8910/eclipseim.jpg

At home, i can't rename or press F2, and i haven't the 'new' menu either etc..